# Select row where value changes and get previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a12 | 1 | 2022-12-01 |
| a12 | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| a12 | 5 | 2023-02-01 |
| z90 | 7 | 2021-01-01 |
| z90 | 7 | 2021-02-01 |
| z90 | 4 | 2021-03-01 |

And I would like to find the date where value changes, and the value it changes from and to:

| id | original_value | date | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a12 | 1 | 2023-02-01 | 5 |
| z90 | 7 | 2021-03-01 | 4 |

The following runs and I'm pretty sure it's doing what I want, but it's also ridiculously slow (45 minutes and counting)! I can see why. I think this will join every row in the table to every ID, and only afterwards select the one where the `DATEADD` is true. But I'm not sure how to do better.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         id, value as new_value, date as date_of_change,
         CASE 
             WHEN value = LAG (value) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
                 THEN 0 
                 ELSE 1 
         END AS Flag
     FROM 
         table) x
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         id, value AS old_value, date 
     FROM 
         table) m ON m.date = DATEADD(month, -1, x.date)
WHERE
    x.Flag = 1
```

Because entries are only once a month so this should work - but if the reliance on `DATEADD` can be removed, that would be more robust.

Comment: Can the same date have two values for the same id?

Comment: @Isolated Each ID can only have one entry per date

Comment: Is there always _one_ value per `id` with a `date` on the first of _every_ month from the first to the last, i.e. months are never missed and dates other than the first of the month never occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG()` partitioned by `id` and not ordered by `id` to get the previous value of each `id`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, 
         LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS original_value,
         date,
         value AS new_value
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE original_value <> new_value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4U43D3V0).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be faster than `LAG`

```sql
select
    t_new.id
    t_new.value,
    t_new.date,
    t_old.value
from
    table t_new
    join table t_old (
        on t_old.date = dateadd (month, -1, t_new.date)
        and t_new.id = t_old.id
    )
where
    t_new.value <> t_old.value
```

Regarding removal of `dateadd`: a think any such attempt will result in use of some kind of ordering, and subsequent loss of performance.

Comment: I think it might be the join that's really making it slow, more than lag. Because I think my join was going to join every row in the table to every ID, then select the one where the dateadd is true after doing that

Comment: @user13948 And have you tested your query? Reading it more closely I believe you have error in your join: it misses `and m.id = x.id` in `on` clause.

Comment: Oh dear... that definitely also explains why it would take forever. Thanks, that might actually fix my method too!